# What is the preferred method to display large pre-rendered animations in android?

Tags: android, animation

I have a series of frame-by-frame animations that are to be incorporated into a program (3 animations at 200-300 frames each). What is the best way to display these in the Android SDK? I have tried using animation lists but these appear to want to buffer all the images simultaneously which causes the device to run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue.
At the moment I’m playing animation with my custom class that derives from ImageView in the onDraw method I read one image from assets folder and assign that image to canvas, every time I check if specific time (60ms in my case) has elapsed and decide if I have to show new image at the end I call postInvalidate() so that onDraw get called again. 
This method is working fine on my HTC Desire but I haven’t got a chance to test on devices with lower specs.
If no one offers a better solution I can’t post my code so other can comment it.

EDIT:

```
    public class AnimationView extends ImageView
    {
private static final String TAG = "AnimView";
//public fields
public String STRING_FORMAT_FOR_PADDING = "%04d";
private String FILE_TYPE = "png";
public boolean STOP_AT_LAST_FRAME = true;
public int DELAY = 60; //delay between frames in milliseconds

//private fields
private boolean mIsPlaying = false;
private boolean mStartPlaying = false;
private Context mContext = null;
private int play_frame = 0;
private long last_tick = 0;
private Bitmap curentFrame = null;
private String dir;
private String prefix;
private int numberOfFrames;
private AnimationViewAnimFinished finishListener;
public AnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;  
}

public void setUpAnimation(String dir, String prefix, int numberOfFrames)
{
    this.dir = dir;
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.numberOfFrames = numberOfFrames;
    curentFrame = loadImage(1);  //set first frame of animation to curent frame

}

public void setAnimationFinishListener(AnimationViewAnimFinished finishListener)
{
    this.finishListener = finishListener;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas c)
{
    //Log.d(TAG, "onDraw called");
    if (mStartPlaying)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "starting animation...");
        play_frame = 1;
        mStartPlaying = false;
        mIsPlaying = true;
        c.drawBitmap(curentFrame,  0, 0, null); // blink fix
        postInvalidate();
    }
    else if (mIsPlaying)
    {
        if (play_frame >= numberOfFrames)
        {
            mIsPlaying = false;
            if (STOP_AT_LAST_FRAME)
            {
                c.drawBitmap(curentFrame,  0, 0, null);
            }
            if (finishListener != null)
                finishListener.animationFinished(); //finish callback called
        }
        else
        {
            long time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - last_tick);
            int draw_x = 0;
            int draw_y = 0;
            if (time >= DELAY) //the delay time has passed. set next frame
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "drawing frame number:"+play_frame+" signature:"+curentFrame.toString());
                last_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                play_frame++;
                curentFrame = loadImage(play_frame);
            }
            c.drawBitmap(curentFrame,  draw_x, draw_y, null);
            postInvalidate();
        }
    }
    else //before animation starts ... drawing first frame
    {
        c.drawBitmap(curentFrame,  0, 0, null);
    }
}

private Bitmap loadImage(int numFrame)
{
    long startOne = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    String name =dir+ prefix + String.format(STRING_FORMAT_FOR_PADDING, numFrame)+"."+FILE_TYPE;

    InputStream ins = null;
    try {
        ins = mContext.getAssets().open(name);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins);
    long endOne = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Log.d(TAG,name+" frame decoded in: "+String.valueOf(endOne-startOne)+" ms");
    return d;

}

//set flag for starting animation to true and inicicate redraw
public void playAnimation()
{
    Log.d(TAG,"Play animation + invalidate()");
    mStartPlaying = true;
    postInvalidate();
}

//callack class for method restaurants
public static abstract class AnimationViewAnimFinished{
    public abstract void animationFinished();
}
```

}

In onCreate method of activity I have this:

```
    animationHolder = (AnimationView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewAnimationHolderService);
    animationHolder.setUpAnimation("animation1/", "frame_", 212);
    animationHolder.setAnimationFinishListener(myAnimationFinishListener);
```

In assets I have folder “animation1” in that folder I have 212 .png images named (frame_0001.png, frame_0002.png, frame_0003.png, …, frame_0212.png)

When I what to start animation I call:

```
    animationHolder.playAnimation();
```

And this is code for animation finish listener:

```
        AnimationViewAnimFinished myAnimationFinishListener = new AnimationViewAnimFinished() {

    @Override
    public void animationFinished() {
        Log.d(TAG,"animation finished");

    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I've also found that you can improve the performance by using a fixed size frame buffer that is populated in concurrent threads.

Comment: @babb517 Can you share your code with fixed size frame buffer and concurrent threads?